# Dynamically calculate moving average based on last 3 day data [PySpark]

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to calculate the moving average for each customer_id and date based on the numbers of the last 3 days. **Eg. to calculate the moving average for the 4th May we would need to compute the mean for the 1st-3rd May of purchase_sum**

I thought of using some sort of window function but I am not quite sure how to calc. the mean based on the last 3 days for a given date and customer_id

Spark DF

```
date        customer_id   purchase_sum
2020-05-01  1             200
2020-05-02  1             243
2020-05-03  1             232
2020-05-04  1             253
2020-05-05  1             221
2020-05-06  1             212
2020-05-07  1             233

2020-05-01  2             323
2020-05-02  2             342
2020-05-03  2             342
2020-05-04  2             311
2020-05-05  2             344
2020-05-06  2             321
2020-05-07  2             345
```

Output Spark DF

```
date        customer_id   purchase_sum  L3D_moving_avg
2020-05-04  1             253           225
2020-05-05  1             221           243
2020-05-06  1             212           235
2020-05-07  1             233           228

2020-05-04  2             311           336
2020-05-05  2             344           332
2020-05-06  2             321           332
2020-05-07  2             345           325
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rangeBetween(start, end)` to create customized window frame boundaries inside your `window` function. The `start` and `end` are relative to the current row.

In your case, it should be `rangeBetween(-3, -1)`. This looks back 3 days from the current `date` allowing you to compute the moving average.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

w=Window().partitionBy("customer_id").orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn('rank', F.dense_rank().over(w))

w2 = (Window().partitionBy("customer_id").orderBy("rank").rangeBetween(-3, -1))

df.select("*", (F.mean("purchase_sum").over(w2)).alias("L3D_moving_avg"))\
        .filter(col("rank")>=4).drop("rank").show()

+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+                        
|      date|customer_id|purchase_sum|    L3D_moving_avg|
+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+
|2020-05-04|          1|         253|             225.0|
|2020-05-05|          1|         221|242.66666666666666|
|2020-05-06|          1|         212|235.33333333333334|
|2020-05-07|          1|         233|228.66666666666666|
|2020-05-04|          2|         311| 335.6666666666667|
|2020-05-05|          2|         344| 331.6666666666667|
|2020-05-06|          2|         321| 332.3333333333333|
|2020-05-07|          2|         345| 325.3333333333333|
+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Perfect ! I was trying to achieve using ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW however, was stucked CURRENT ROW - 1, can we have something in ROWS between , that will take CURRENT ROW -1 (previous of the current row ?)

Comment: why don't you use `F.avg` instead of `F.sum/3`?

Comment: @dsk you can use Window.rowsBetween(-2,-1)

Comment: @dsk, yes you can use `rowsBetween(-3, -1)`. Since I'm ordering by rank here, both [rangeBetween](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.WindowSpec.rangeBetween) and [rowsBetween](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.WindowSpec.rowsBetween) would give the same results. 
@mck, sure.